# Flex 4 - Embedding Multiple MP3's

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, embed, flex4.5, audio

I have an mp3 embedded in a Flex application with a start and stop button. Using this code...

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[ 
import mx.core.SoundAsset; 
import flash.media.*; 

[Embed(source="assets/pie-yan-knee.mp3")] 
[Bindable] 
public var Song:Class; 

public var mySong:SoundAsset = new Song() as SoundAsset; 
public var channel:SoundChannel;

public function playSound():void
{ 
  stopSound(); 
  channel = mySong.play();
}

public function stopSound():void
{
  if ( channel != null ) channel.stop();
} 
]]>
</fx:Script> 

<s:HGroup> 
<s:Button label="play" click="playSound();"/> <s:Button label="stop"
  click="stopSound();"/> 
</s:HGroup>
```

I want to have multiple instances with different sounds though.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make a separate class reference for each:

```
[Embed(source="assets/song1.mp3")] 
[Bindable] 
public var Song1:Class; 
[Embed(source="assets/song2.mp3")] 
[Bindable] 
public var Song2:Class; 
[Embed(source="assets/song3.mp3")] 
[Bindable] 
public var Song3:Class;
```

Comment: There must be other alterations that need doing, Im getting an error '-1151: A conflict exists with definition sndChannel in namespace internal.' on all of the sounds.

Comment: I made some other changes and its now working so you pointed me in the right direction.
Thanks :)